# How to fix "NoClassDefFoundError: midterm/Main" when I'm running scala app?

Tags: java, scala, noclassdeffounderror

I try to compile this code

```
import java.awt.Color
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JPanel;


object Main{
    var panel = new JPanel
    var btn= new JButton
    def main(args:Array[Int]):Unit={
      btn.setBounds(80,80,80,80)
      btn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      panel.add(btn);
  }  
}
```

when I typed `scalac Main.scala` the classfile was created successfully,but after scala Main 
there was output like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: midterm/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: midterm.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: midterm.Main.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a package issue. Ensure that `Main.scala` is located in a directory called `midterm`. Then use:

```
scalac midterm/Main.scala
```

from the directory that contains the `midterm` sub-directory. Also ensure that the file contains the `package` declaration:

```
package midterm
```

---

Also your `main` method entry point method should have a `String` array rather than an `Int` one:

```
def main(args:Array[Int]):Unit={
```

should be

```
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
```

With these changes it compiles fine with `Scala 2.10.0`.

Comment: output is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: midterm/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: midterm.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Comment: Pasting a stack trace in a comment is really unhelpful.  Update your question with the new code and error instead.